# how c++ implements runtime type info

Tags: c++, rtti

I want to know how the C++ language can save the type information of variables at runtime. In my opinion, the runtime means that the source code file written by the programmer is compiled into the binary format machine code related to the specific machine. This binary file is all composed of machine instructions and operands. At the machine level, there is no such thing. The concept of type is only the values stored in registers and memory. These values have no upper-level abstract type from the perspective of the machine. So how do you store these type information at runtime, which is the process of machine code execution? How should I understand the statement of runtime type information?

Comment: You can always store some extra data in your machine code, that data can contain information about types, which you retrieve in some fashion

Comment: What do you believe that you need to "understand" any of that? I have very little knowledge of that, yet, somehow I've been able to do lots of things in C++, for many, many years, despite that?

Comment: The c++ standard says very little (if anything at all) about how RTTI is implemented, typically implementations store the type info somewhere in the vtable of the object

Comment: @AlanBirtles In my opinion, the so-called runtime information is not a runtime behavior at all, because there is no concept of type at the machine code level. The runtime type information should be the behavior of the compiler. When the compiler compiles the code, Analyze the real type of an object in a specific statement, and then specify the code that it actually calls according to its real type, such as polymorphism. Therefore, this designation should be determined after compilation, and there is no type information involved at runtime. I don't know if this understanding is correct?

Answer (score 2):

There are two scenarios.

If the value being inspected has a polymorphic type, the compiler could, for example, generate code that somehow maps the object's vtable to a static type information block. This block might even inside the vtable!

If the value being inspected has a fully-known static type, the compiler can simply insert a pointer to that object's type info directly.

The answer you get will vary enormously from compiler to compiler, but I did some research for a simple program compiled with GCC.
For example, given the following definitions:

```
template <class T>
const char* get_typeid(const T& val) {
    return typeid(val).name();
}

class Static{};
class Dynamic {
    public: virtual ~Dynamic() = default; // Making the class polymorphic
};
```

The compiler can generate the following code for Static:

```
char const* get_typeid<Static>(Static const&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:typeinfo for Static
        call    std::type_info::name() const
        leave
        ret
```

Note how it accesses a global constant ("OFFSET FLAT:typeinfo for Static"). That means the compiler has resolved the `typeid` call at compile time.

Compare to the Dynamic version:

```
char const* get_typeid<Dynamic>(Dynamic const&):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8] # rax = pointer to Dynamic
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax] # rax = vtable pointer of Dynamic
        sub     rax, 8
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rax] #rax = typeinfo field of vtable
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    std::type_info::name() const
        leave
        ret
```

Note how it access the type info by getting the passed Dynamic object's vtable and subtracting 8. For completeness, here is the definition of a Dynamic vtable:

```
vtable for Dynamic:
        .quad   0
        .quad   typeinfo for Dynamic
        .quad   Dynamic::~Dynamic() [complete object destructor] # this is where the vtable normally points to.
        .quad   Dynamic::~Dynamic() [deleting destructor]
```

Comment: @Botjie In my opinion, the so-called runtime information is not a runtime behavior at all, because there is no concept of type at the machine code level. The runtime type information should be the behavior of the compiler. When the compiler compiles the code, Analyze the real type of an object in a specific statement, and then specify the code that it actually calls according to its real type, such as polymorphism. Therefore, this designation should be determined after compilation, and there is no type information involved at runtime. I don't know if this understanding is correct?

Comment: @Botijie why called runtime, is really mislead one's mind. I donot know how it appeared.

Comment: @Botijie Do you think my understanding is correct? Do you think my understanding is correct?

Comment: It is called **runtime** type information because it allows a program to recover type information at runtime (either via `typeid` or `dynamic_cast`), whereas a compiler throws away all type information when compiling to machine code. That the compiler has to insert additional code to enable this is an implementation detail. Compare C++ to Java: in Java every object has a runtime Class object associated with it, while in C++ as much as possible is resolved at compile time, leaving only polymorphic objects with a link to their type.

Comment: @Botijie Therefore, in order to provide runtime information behavior, the compiler will actually add a data structure of a table storing type information to the generated machine code. When querying type information at runtime, it is actually a process of looking up a table. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what my answer demonstrates for both polymorphic and non-polymorphic cases.

Comment: In any case, machine code has no type information. The so-called runtime can easily mislead programmers who do not have much computer knowledge. Many books will not introduce this concept in detail, but it is necessary for us to understand it deeply, which is related to the meaning of the program. . In many cases, it is the extra work done by the compiler. The so-called continuous iteration of language versions and the emergence of new grammars are actually an update iteration of the compiler.

Comment: As long as the hardware configuration of the machine remains unchanged, the machine code is always there, without rich and colorful functions. No matter how the high-level programming language changes, the code corresponding to the bottom layer is the ugly simple machine instructions.

Comment: You actually don't have to know how RTTI is implemented by the compiler to use it, just like many other abstractions C++ gives you (memory management, various data structures, etc). Abstraction is a useful and necessary concept for programmers.